# hide the div on page load

Tags: html, css

I want to hide the div(Togglethis button) on pageload and when clicked on Tab2 the hidden div should be visible, again when clicked on Tab1 the div(Togglethis button) should be hidden.Can i achieve this using angularjs and bootstrap instead of using css/javascript tricks

Comment: AngularJS and Bootstrap **ARE** javascript and css!

Answer (score 2):

it is easy... just use `ng-show/ng-hide`

add this to your controller

```
$scope.shouldButtonHidden = true;
```

add this to your html

```
<label ng-hide="shouldButtonHidden" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="" uib-btn-radio="ToggleThis">Togglethis
```

and change shouldButtonHidden to true/false based on which tab you are at in the ng-click

http://plnkr.co/edit/XoJR5D90rNFagvbNnios?p=preview